# How to blur background image of div, without blurring the remaining site or the content of the div

Tags: html, css, background-image, blur

I'm trying to figure out how to blur the background image of a div. The goal is to only blur the background image of the div and not the background of the page itself or the div contents.

Here is an example div:

```
<header class="intro">
  <div class="background-image"></div>
  <div class="intro-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
          <h1 class="brand-heading">Grayscale</h1>
          <p class="intro-text">A free, responsive, one page Bootstrap theme.
            <br>Created by Start Bootstrap.</p>
          <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Lora", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.intro {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 100px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.intro .background-image {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-image: url(https://previews.123rf.com/images/denisovd/denisovd1203/denisovd120301652/12705959-wall-of-wooden-barrels-Stock-Photo-barrels-whiskey-cellar.jpg) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.intro .intro-body {
  z-index: 9999;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here is the JS fiddle containing the CSS I've tried:
http://jsfiddle.net/80jzdvqp/

I would high appreciate some help!

Comment: something like this one?? [ http://jsfiddle.net/p3LmaL2p/ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
<body><header class="intro">
  <div class="background-image"></div>
  <div class="intro-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
          <h1 class="brand-heading">Grayscale</h1>
          <p class="intro-text">A free, responsive, one page Bootstrap theme.
            <br>Created by Start Bootstrap.</p>
          <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
</body>
```

Css :

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "Lora", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.intro {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 100px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.intro .background-image {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/html-color-codes-color-tutorials-hero-00e10b1f.jpg);
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
}

.intro .intro-body {
  z-index: 9999;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work... it looks like the `.intro-body` has to turn off the blurring. I mashed together some other examples and I got this: http://jsfiddle.net/86vy48hv/

Comment: Could you fork the example and paste the link?

Comment: you problem is you are using a z-index in a wrong way

Comment: the height: could not be set to auto, you have to add 100% to the .intro .background-image after setting the z-index to -1 and change the background-image to background only, and remove the background color!

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help.

Comment: happy to help!Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

I have created a example using `div`, this includes a `parent div,image and text`. Now if I don't apply any `position` to `elements` present inside then they will `align one after another`, but to make `image` as `background` of `div` I have set it's `position` as `absolute` and using `filter` you can apply `blur` to the `image` and then using `z-index align` them i.e text and image. Hope this helps.

> The filter property provides graphical effects like blurring,
>   sharpening, or color shifting an element. Filters are commonly used to
>   adjust the rendering of images, backgrounds, and borders.

```css
div{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
div > img{
  width:auto;
  height:100%;
  z-index:1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  filter:blur(10px);
}
div > p{
  text-align:center;
  top:60px;
  z-index:9;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Demo text.Demo text.Demo text.Demo text.Demo text.</p>
<img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/denisovd/denisovd1203/denisovd120301652/12705959-wall-of-wooden-barrels-Stock-Photo-barrels-whiskey-cellar.jpg">
</div>
```